# searchable dropdown list in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

issue in locating the element in searchable drop down list.

Can anyone help with that.Below is the HTML code.

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jdyl.jpg)

Mycode for drop down list.

```
    element.all(by.css('.chosen-single:nth-child(1)')).get(0).click();
    browser.sleep(5000);
    element.all(by.css('ul.chosen-results > li:nth-child(3)')).click();
    browser.sleep(5000);
```

and tried with this also

```
element(
by.xpath("/[@id='content']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/
           div[1]/div[3]/div/span/span/span[2]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate the dropdown element and send the desired item value with `sendKeys()`.

Working example, using the [Kendo UI dropdown list demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index):

```
describe("Kendo UI dropdown", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index");
    });

    it("should select orange color", function () {
        $("span.k-dropdown").click().sendKeys("Orange").sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);

        // expect smth
    });
});
```

Comment: HI alecxe,now getting error as "undefined is not a function".Send keys is not working for me.For normal dropdowns it is working but for searchable drop downs it is not.